# Delete leading characters from the active cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

The code below deletes 123 leading characters from a text string in a range of cells. What I've been trying to figure out without luck is to change it to delete the leading characters from  the active cell instead of the range of cells. I tried to change it to For each cell in Active.Cell..... but it did not work. Can somebody help me out with this?

```
Sub Del()
Dim cell As Object

    For Each cell In Range("A2:A10")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        cell.Value = Right(cell, Len(cell) - 123)
        Columns("A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If

    Next cell
```

Comment: Your code has no clause to handle those cells with less than 123 characters. Add a clause to handle this situation otherwise the loop can error out. Also I would change it to be cell.value = Right(cell.value, Len(cell.value)-123). Cell and Cell.Value are not the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub Del()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

ActiveCell.Value = Right(ActiveCell, Len(ActiveCell) - 123)

End Sub